# Best way to calculate page count while creating a PDF in Quartz?

Tags: ios, count, pdf-generation, quartz-2d

My app creates a pdf page from app data, using Quartz and UIGraphics.
Basically I define a `CGRect docRect` to fit on that page, then increment an `NSInteger yOffset` each time I draw something.
If `yOffset` gets larger than `docRect.size.height` I do a `UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()`.
This works fine, BUT:

I would like to draw a page count at the bottom, like "**Page X of Y**".

**X** is obviously easy to tell, but at the moment when I create a new page, I don't know how large **Y** might be.

I see 2 possible solutions for this:

1. After drawing all pages, reiterate through all pages and add the counter.
   Problem: As far as I can tell, after calling `UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()` there is no way to return back to previous pages. Is anyone able to disconfirm that?
2. Calculate all `yOffset` increments in advance to get the total page count. 
   Possible, but IMHO not really an elegant solution.

Has anyone advice on this problem?

Thanks in advance, m

Comment: I am currently facing a similar problem.  Please post if you found a work-around, or anyone who has any suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to pre-calculate the sizes of everything to determine in advance how many pages you'll have, one option is to render in two passes, much like you mention in your question. Render the first pass to *temp.pdf* and leave room for the page number counter.

If working through the source content is a memory or performance burden, the second pass can go to *final.pdf*, using *temp.pdf* as an input. Loop through all the pages of *temp.pdf*, using `CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages` to get your page count. Draw each page from *temp.pdf* via `CGContextDrawPDFPage`, followed by drawing the page counter.

When you're done, delete *temp.pdf* as cleanup, and you're all set.

**Update**: Something along the lines of this untested code, summarized from some previous work:

```
...
CGPDFDocumentRef tempDocRef = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)tempPdfUrl);
size_t pageCount = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(docRef);
CGContextRef finalPdfContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)finalPdfUrl, &defaultPageRect, nil);

for (int pageNum = 1; pageNum <= pageCount; pageNum++) {
  CGPDFPageRef tempPageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(tempDocRef, pageNum+1);
  CGPDFContextBeginPage(finalPdfContext, nil);
  CGContextDrawPDFPage(finalPdfContext, tempPageRef);

  // do your page number rendering here, using pageNum and pageCount
  ...

  CGPDFContextEndPage(finalPdfContext);
  CGPDFPageRelease(tempPageRef);
}

CGPDFDocumentRelease(tempDocRef);
CGContextRelease(finalPdfContext);
...
```

Comment: I understand that's how it should be done in theory, but unless I'm missing something, there's no CoreGraphics API for opening an existing PDF file.  There is just the UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData and UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile methods.  To do a 2-pass approach, we would need some kind of UIGraphicsOpenPDFContextFromFile method, or something similar.

Comment: I updated my post to include some code that shows how to work with a PDF from CoreGraphics, which offers more than UIKit.

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusion's Essential PDF provides a solution to this problem. It provides solution for the problem in two situation

1. While generating the PDF Document.
2. After the generation of the PDF document

You can try the online sample in the link http://mvc.syncfusion.com/sfreportingmvcsamplebrowser/MVC/10.1.0.44/Pdf_MVC/Samples/4.0/Settings/HeadersFooters

-Suresh

Answer (score -1):

Better late than never - If this is still something your looking for an answer to, I think you might be interested in checking out this link - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH10-SW1 - Apple provides a (void)drawPageNumber:(NSInteger)pageNum to accomplish this task.